# Microsoft Report Shows an Error Privacy Statement

Tags: windows-runtime, privacy, runtimeexception, microsoft-reporting

In my **Windows Application** project the **Microsoft Report Shows an Error Privacy Statement** on **Client Machine** , Not on my Machine

Microsoft Report works on Client Machine very well.

This Error does not shows on **Runtime** , but after closing the Application this **Error** appears

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after alonge years I found that I must **first** close the form that contains the **Report Viewer** before calling the `Application.Exit();` method.
because the **Report Viewer** session still working if I called this method directly without closing the form of **Report Viewer** and this causes the problem above.